# Handling MouseEvents in Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qgraphicsview

Sorry for my beginner's question... 
What is the easiest way to define procedures, which are executed when MousePressEvent or MouseReleaseEvent occurs?

For now I am defining my own class (MyGraphicsView class), which inherits QGraphicsView and I am reimplementing mouse events (which are virtual functions). It works fine but is there any way to solve this problem without a need to define a new class?
Can I connect Events with Slots somehow?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/15564-Signals-amp-Slots-question) on the Qt Centre forum describes quite well what your options are. Simply put:

1. Do what you are doing (ie subclassing and reimplementing)
2. Work with an event filter as described in the thread and link therein.

Comment: Marcin, In your case the best way is the 2nd point (Using event filter)

Answer (score 2):

Because the mouse events are protected virtual functions, the easiest approach is exactly what you are doing.  I don't see any reason why defining a subclass would cause a problem, so I say stick with what you have.

If you really want to connect the events with slots, you can make your subclass implementation of `mousePressEvent()`, for example, simply `emit mousePressSignal()`.  Of course, you would also need to declare `mousePressSignal()` in the `signals` section of the subclass header.

Answer (score 1):

I can see no problem with overriding `QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent` and `QGraphisView::mouseReleaseEvent`. The whole `QGraphicsView`/`QGraphicsScene`/`QGraphicsItem` event-handling concept is built around virtual event-handling functions.

Additionally, also the [Qt documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qgraphicsview.html#details) suggests that "you can provide your own custom scene interaction, by creating a subclass of `QGraphicsView`, and reimplementing the mouse and key event handlers."

Answer (score 0):

From your question,

> is there any way to
>   solve this problem without having to
>   define a new class?

The answer is **No**. **You can't**.

You have to have inherit from the class that you want to handle the events.

> Can I connect Events with Slots
>   somehow?

**No**. **You cannot connect events to slots** but only signals can be connected to slots.

The way you are now doing is the way to do.

Comment: Wrong, one can install event filters, or, in the case of QGRaphicsView, also scene event filters.

Comment: @ Frank, Yes one can install event filters but you cannot connect events to the slots.. Within the event handler you can emit the signal but even then only a signal can be connected with a slot and not an event..

Answer (score 0):

You can use event filters: See http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qobject.html#eventFilter
Or, for graphics items in particular, http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qgraphicsitem.html#sceneEventFilter

Note that for the latter, some events change: QMouseEvent becomes QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent for example, so make sure to filter for the right type.

What is easier, depends on the situation. If you have a subclass anyway, reimplementing the virtual method is often more straight-forward than the event filter approach. But if you want to track several widgets from several different classes and need special handling for a certain event, subclassing just for this purpose is tedious and not a good design (and makes e.g. using designer for those widgets harder).