# c++ How to take pixel coordinates from an image?

Tags: c++, qt, coordinates, pixel

I have an image in C++ and I want to take the coordinates of a pixel (relatives to the image) clicking on it (with my picture available and open to click on it). I don't know how to define the signal and the slot required to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Since you mention signals and slots I guess you are using QT, so I've added the QT tag.

Comment: Yes, I forgot it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event){
//blabla
if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress) {
QMouseEvent* MouseEvGrip = (QMouseEvent*)event;
Point2f clickePixel((float)MouseEvGrip->x(), (float)MouseEvGrip->y());
//blabla
}
}
```

Comment: You might want to check the sending ``obj``, too. See http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qobject.html#eventFilter for another example and how to embed ``eventFilter`` into your application.

Comment: You also should accept the event so that it prevents other widgets from trying to use the button press.

Answer (score 1):

There are events offered for your case. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449277/) for further instructions.

I assume you are using a control to display the image that is derived from `QWidget`, e.g. [`QImage`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html).
`QWidget`-derived classes can handle mouse events like clicking and send a [`QMouseEvent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmouseevent.html). This contains the *x*- and *y*-coordinates *relative to the widget that received the event.*
Use these to read the pixel value by calling `QImage::pixel(x, y)` (returning a `QRgb`).